# How to exchange Polars-DataFrame between Rust and Python

Tags: python, numpy, rust, pyo3, python-polars

I want to write a `Python extension` using `Rust` with `Ctypes` or `Pyo3` to get better performance than native Python. But how to exchange data such as `Polars` `DataFrame` or `ndarray` type between Rust and Python?

Comment: See: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/tree/master/examples/python_rust_compiled_function

Comment: Thanks for reply, I noticed that `fn array_to_rust` in the example has a comment `/// Take an arrow array from python and convert it to a rust arrow array.` , so is this means the other three func will copy data?  If the data from rust is used to create a DataFrame, is `rust_series_to_py_series` more efficient?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75292316/example-of-zero-copy-share-of-a-polars-dataframe-between-python-and-rust

Comment: And: https://medium.com/@niklas.molin/0-copy-you-pyarrow-array-to-rust-23b138cb5bf2