# Example of zero-copy share of a Polars dataframe between Python and Rust?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

I have a Python function such as

def add_data(input_df):
"""
some manipulation of input_df (Polars dataframe) such as filling some columns with new values
"""

I would like to use this function from a Rust function. input_df can be tens of megabytes big, so I'd like to use zero-copy share between Python and Rust. Is there any example code on this available?

I found [Is it possible to access underlying data from Polars in cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102526/is-it-possible-to-access-underlying-data-from-polars-in-cython/73113179#73113179) but this seems to be Cython. I am looking for a pure Python way.

Comment: Did you look at [ffi.rs](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/examples/python_rust_compiled_function/src/ffi.rs#L34) and lib.rs? It uses [PyO3](https://pyo3.rs/v0.18.0/python_from_rust.html#calling-python-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I made a crate for this to make this easy: https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars

See the examples to get started: https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars/tree/main/example

Comment: Thanks. I see that this example sends dataframe from Python to Rust. My use case is that Rust is the main program and it will use pyo3 to call a method of a Python class. Thus, DataFrame is sent from Rust to Python. Is any such example available as well?

Comment: There is no example, but the same should be possible with those extension types.

Comment: @ritchie46 From looking at the crate, I'm not sure how converting from a Rust DataFrame to a Python DataFrame is zero-copy. It looks like `into_py` [calls `clone` on every Series in the DataFrame.](https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars/blob/0165cb4f6795bf9a08fe04473aba408a02119b91/pyo3-polars/src/lib.rs#L182) Does that not constitute a complete copy of the DataFrame's data? I have to admit that I might be misunderstanding something here as I have very little experience with Rust.

Comment: No the data is behind an `Arc`. So we only increment a reference count.

Comment: hopefully, there is a working example. I searched around with Google and couldn't find one. LOL, I have read all the materials I found and still couldn't fully understand how to convert rust polars dataframe to python pandas/polars dataframe.